# resizing multiple fields of image

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have a form where some image file fields are, submitting all those value to my controller,
After Receiving all fields i'm able to resize only one field of image file rest of image fields are not going to resizing.

Here is my view

```
<input type="file" name="image" size="20" />
<input type="file" name="image2" size="20" />
<input type="submit" value="upload" />
```

here is my controller

```
public function resizeImage($filename){
  $source_path = './upload/' . $filename;
  $target_path = './upload/';
  $config_manip = array(
    'image_library' => 'gd2',
    'source_image' => $source_path,
    'new_image' => $target_path,
    'maintain_ratio' => TRUE,
    'width' => 500,
  );
  $this->load->library('image_lib', $config_manip);
  if (!$this->image_lib->resize()) {
     echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
  }
  $this->image_lib->clear();
}

public function uploadImage() { 
  $config['upload_path']   = './upload/'; 
  $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png'; 
  $config['max_size']      = 1024;
  $this->load->library('upload', $config);
  if ($this->upload->do_upload('image')) {
      $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors()); 
      $uploadedImage = $this->upload->data();
      $this->resizeImage($uploadedImage['file_name']);
      print_r('Image Uploaded Successfully.');
      /*exit;*/
  }
  if ($this->upload->do_upload('image2')) {
      $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors()); 
      $uploadedImage = $this->upload->data();
      $this->resizeImage($uploadedImage['file_name']);
      print_r('Image Uploaded Successfully.');
      /*exit;*/
   } 
}
```

To resize image i have made a function where i'm passing the image details and image can be resize their size. But its only resizing only one time, second time image uploading with their normal size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use codeigniter upload library, to change the config you must use `initialize`.

```
public function resizeImage($filename){
  $source_path = './upload/' . $filename;
  $target_path = './upload/';
  $config_manip = array(
    'image_library' => 'gd2',
    'source_image' => $source_path,
    'new_image' => $target_path,
    'maintain_ratio' => TRUE,
    'width' => 500,
  );
  //change load library to initialize
  $this->image_lib->initialize($config_manip); 
  if (!$this->image_lib->resize()) {
     echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
  }
  $this->image_lib->clear();
}

$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->load->library('image_lib');//load library outside your resizeImage function
  if ($this->upload->do_upload('image')) {
      $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors()); 
      $uploadedImage = $this->upload->data();
      $this->resizeImage($uploadedImage['file_name']);
      print_r('Image Uploaded Successfully.');
      /*exit;*/
  }
  if ($this->upload->do_upload('image2')) {
      $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors()); 
      $uploadedImage = $this->upload->data();
      $this->resizeImage($uploadedImage['file_name']);
      print_r('Image Uploaded Successfully.');
      /*exit;*/
   }
```